# Can't get Angular Material Stepper with single form and child component forms working

Tags: angular, angular-material-stepper

I'm trying to implement the Angular Material Stepper functionality in our application. Based on the documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#using-a-single-form) I came up with the following solution:

`civilliability-proposal-detail.component.html`

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom" formArrayName="formArray" #stepper>
    <mat-step formGroupName="0" [stepControl]="formArray?.get([0])" [editable]="true">
      <div>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ 'proposals.details.civilLiability.stepper.details' | translate }}</ng-template>
        <app-civilliability-step1 [model]="model.details"></app-civilliability-step1>

        <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step formGroupName="1" [stepControl]="formArray?.get([1])" [editable]="true">
      <div>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ 'proposals.details.civilLiability.stepper.antecedents' | translate }}</ng-template>
        <!-- <app-civilliability-step2 [model]="model.questionnaire"></app-civilliability-step2> -->

        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</form>
```

`civilliability-proposal-detail.component.ts`

```
get formArray(): AbstractControl | null {
  return this.formGroup.get('formArray');
}

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.buildForms();
}

buildForms() {
  this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    formArray: this.formBuilder.array([this.buildDetailsForm(), this.buildQuestionnaireForm()])
  });
}

buildDetailsForm(): FormGroup {
  if (typeof this.model === 'undefined') {
    this.model = getEmptyCivilLiabilityRequest();
  }

  const formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    horses: new FormControl(this.model.details.horses, Validators.min(0)),
    properties: new FormControl(this.model.details.properties, Validators.min(0)),
    garages: new FormControl(this.model.details.garages, Validators.min(0)),
    ...
  });

  return formGroup;
}

buildQuestionnaireForm(): FormGroup {
  const formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({});

  return formGroup;
}
```

`civilliability-step1.component.html`

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <section class="row">
    <section class="col-md-4 full-width-form">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>{{ 'proposals.details.civilLiability.horses' | translate }}</mat-label>
        <input type="number" matInput formControlName="horses" />
        <mat-error>{{ formGroup.controls['horses'].getError('server-error') }}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-4 full-width-form">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>{{ 'proposals.details.civilLiability.terrainsWithTrees' | translate }}</mat-label>
        <input type="number" matInput formControlName="terrainsWithTrees" />
        <mat-error>{{ formGroup.controls['terrainsWithTrees'].getError('server-error') }}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-4 full-width-form">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>{{ 'proposals.details.civilLiability.garages' | translate }}</mat-label>
        <input type="number" matInput formControlName="garages" />
        <mat-error>{{ formGroup.controls['garages'].getError('server-error') }}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </section>
  </section>
</form>
```

Based on this I get a bunch of errors which I think are related to the fact that I'm using child components in my form, but I'm not quite sure how to tackle this. So, any suggestions?

I've also read somebody **not** using the `formArrayName` in the stepper, but I can't seem to find this example anymore, so can't test if that works or not.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried initialising the forms in individual child components rather than using the `formArray`? You can then get the output using event emitters/public properties from the child components.

Comment: So you mean instead of initialising the forms in my parent component, I initialise  them in the child component, right? I'm not quite sure how to use the stepper without the formArray though, since it's not documented (or I just can't find it)

Comment: Yes, having individual form groups in each step's child component. If I can find the code, I'll provide a stackblitz example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a form array, I would recommend declaring a form group in each individual step component. Here is how I have done it:

1. Create a component to keep the stepper.
2. Create a component for each step and initialise it in the step component.
3. Use public component variables or define a model to keep user input.
4. You can then access the public members of each step component in the parent stepper component via data binding.

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-stepper-with-individual-components)

Comment: Your solution was a great idea and it got my slider working! I did change one thing though. Instead of having the get step1() step2 and sterp3() I've removed those and added this in the html: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxr8H.png